# USC google maps ajax + json

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

Are there any tutorials on how to get as advanced with the google maps api as: http://web-app.usc.edu/maps/#upc

Specifically, I want to know how to use json for the search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For search, there are lots of options.

Google has a Store Locator tutorial at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html.

The Mobile Web Framework has a Locations API with search capabilities. http://mwf.ucla.edu/

And there's many more out there.

For a tutorial on some of the other things that are done on the page you're talking about (overlaying an image on the map, etc.), allow me to recommend my own long, boring video on making mobile maps that aren't terrible.  It all applies to non-mobile maps too, though.  http://www.youtube.com/playlist?p=PL3717ABA3A1A35B7E